# I can't view my website in internet explorer browser after move from apache to nginx, while it work and look good in firefox

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, nginx

After installation of nginx webserver, i run my website in firefox. It works good in firefox, i can see my website template is looks good, but in internet explorer it is not working properly, i can't see my webpage has text and images and every content in bad style. Like images are not loading, may be css is not working. Please help me to sort out this problem.

Before this i was running my website on apache with different ip address and moved to nginx.
Tanks saurav

Comment: Check for hard-coded addresses in the src attributes in various tags?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that nginx is passing the Content-Type: header to the browser correctly.

Internet Explorer relies on the Content-Type header to treat the object applicably, whilst WebKit/Mozilla/Gecko are able to interpret the content and make an assumption based on the bitstream itself.

Answer (score 0):

clear your cache in both and make sure it's still working in one and not the other. Attempt to load the css url in the browser directly i.e. http://domain.com/styles/style.css. View the source and verify the src addresses are correct. Check the sites error logs for any access denied or "not found" lines.

Answer (score 0):

the mime types are probably not configured.  In your http{} block, you need the include like the following:

```
http { 
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```